# Update UserProperties In Firebase Analytics during Debug Mode

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm Implemented Firebase Analytics in my app, during LogIn and Logout I need to set different user properties(4 different properties) based on login user. For testing, I am using DEBUG View from firebase console to check events are triggering and user properties are updating properly. Events are perfectly working, but user properties are not reflecting immediate in debug view. When I click the Event in debug view, we can able to see their respective user properties.

While doing these, I'm seeing new event with old user properties.[i.e., New Events from New User but User Properties for this new events is coming form OLD User]. So it taking time few minutes to updates the user properties.

How to avoid this wrong mapping?